# Is there ever a silent B in "combo"?

Tags: pronunciation, silent-letter

I know that certain letters are not always pronounced in English words, at least not by all people or in all dialects. For example, for the word *mountain*, there seems to be at least two native pronunciations, and it seems to me sometimes the *t* is not pronounced. Notice that the middle of *mountain* contains a nasal sound (*n*) followed by a stop (*t*). This same enviornment exists in *combo* with *m* and *b*.

I can't hear the *b* in *combo breaker* in this [video from the game *Killer Instinct*](https://youtu.be/rPseOlTl7Dk). So I began to wonder if sometimes the *b* is not pronounced in *combo* like the *t* is not pronounced in *mountain*.

There is also this video (['How to pronounce *combo*'](https://youtu.be/ZdF1ir2gfOM)); I don't know if English speakers always pronounce the *b*.

Background note:
I have always heard the word combo without any silent letter almost everywhere but not in the video game Killer Instinct. When I was a kid I used to play this game and tried to repeat the phrase "combo breaker" but I wasn't close to it because I didn't understand any English nor was trying to learn. So, today my niece was saying the same thing I used to say when I was a kid and I thought, wow! I need to find out the right pronunciation and got on YouTube and found this video and I heard "combo breaker" but with *silent b* so I thought I would ask where this English comes from and here I am asking. Check the link I gave to hear, or should I say watch, the video? Anyway the video makes the same sound as the Killer Instinct I used to play. I thought I should give this little extra piece of information just so you know.

Comment: I can hear the b. Anyway, this is heavily synthesized speech, so why would you use it to critique correct pronunciation?

Comment: No no I didn't want it to sound as a critique just plain curiosity I can see I still have to work on tuning my ears thanks though.

Comment: And just wanted to know if silent b was ok in this word as many other words that you can say in different ways you know but hey atleast I got the correct way of saying "combo breaker" anyway, right?

Comment: I suppose if you said it fast 10 times, the "b" in combo might weaken or disappear, due to the "b" in breaker. But that is a tongue-twister, not normal pronunciation.

Comment: Now say whatever you want but I can't still hear the b even if I try or set my mind there is a b there in the sound unlike this othere video the b and every other letter are present a hundred percent. Check it out: https://youtu.be/ZdF1ir2gfOM

Comment: This is a _sound track_ to a _**video game,**_ for heaven's sake. The pronunciation is slurred, but the **b** is there. There is no _National Language Commissariat_ which enforces proper diction in the sound tracks of video games. The producers will not be fined or imprisoned for this breach of the _Illegal Pronunciation Statute._ They can say anything they want, in any way they see fit.

Comment: Goddamned! I never said it was illegal neither was I pointing my finger in a negative way or anything like that. I was just asking for the opinion or maybe the knowledge of where that word without b was coming from but you're saying there is a b in the first video well that MIGHT BE your mind. If you see the answer in this thread the person had good manners and a well brained head to understand I'm a learner and as such have a lot of questions and curiosity regarding the beautiful English language. Well it is to me, may not be for you but I find exciting when I learn a new word.

Comment: I think that if someone doesn't have the patience or is pissed off at anytime shouldn't be commeting about a question in this site. And just to let you know, just in case you don't know. There are many softwares and services that sound robotic or very unhuman but they all make the b sound one example is Google Translate and just to clarify that phrase "combo breaker" the sound in the video game was a fad when I was a kid and many people still find it really cool and I always wanted to say it right. Just to make things a lil more clear, read my next comment.

Comment: The word mauntain Americans say it in two different ways if not more but all I know is two, one where the T is pronounced and the other where not and that's because people from different sides of country or jus different race. So I thought Well, I should ask. That's why I asked. You should try to understand better if not, shouldn't be trying to answer nor commenting stuff just because you can. that's all I going to say for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game clearly prounounces the *b* in [this other video from *Killer Insinct*](https://youtu.be/9PfIZo5R19U?t=37s) at about 38 seconds. Even though this is a computerized pronunciation, it's easy to hear the *b*. The style of "speech" in the video you ask about is hardly natural.

In addition, the *b* is pronounced in 'combo' in the video *[How to pronounce 'combo'](https://youtu.be/ZdF1ir2gfOM).* The learner may also wish to listen to humans (rather than the computerized voice in the video game) pronouncing 'combo' at [Forvo](http://forvo.com/word/combo/#en). One speaker does so with a British English accent and one with an Anerican English accent. In both examples, the *b* is pronounced.

Regarding the letter *t*, this letter is often pronounced as an alveolar tap or a glottal stop, depending on the vocal context and the dialect of the speaker. You can search the ELL site or the internet for 'alveolar tap' and find more information.

Comment: And looking at your answer all I can say is I would give more arrows up if it was possible and double or triple aprove as well.